# Some questions on the proof of Hoelders inequality.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

I have some questions about the proof of Hoelder's inequality.

Statement: Let $(X, \mathbb X, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $p,q > 1$  with $1/p+1/q = 1$ and suppose that $f \in L_p(X)$ and $g \in L_q(X)$. Then $fg \in L_1(X)$ and $\|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$.

Proof: Let $f \in L_p$ and $g \in L_q$. If either $\|f\|_p = 0$ or $\|g\|_q = 0$ then $fg = 0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere and the inequality follows. So we assume $\|f\|_p \ne 0$ and $\|g\|_q \ne 0$. We now let $x \in X$, $A = \frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|_p}$ and $B = \frac{|g(x)|}{\|g\|_q}$. We can now apply Young's inequality for $A$ and $B$ to get that
\begin{align*}
\frac{|f(x)||g(x)|}{\|f\|_p \|g\|_q} \le \frac{|f(x)|^p}{p \|f\|_p^p} + \frac{|g(x)|^q}{q\|g\|_q^q}.
\end{align*}
Since $f^p$ and $g^q$ are integrable it follows that $fg$ is integrable and so $fg \in L_1(X)$. If we integrate both sides with respect to $\mu$ we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\|f\|_p \|g\|_q} \int |f(x)g(x)| \, d\mu(x) \le \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1
\Longrightarrow \|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q.
\end{align*}

The following implications I don't understand:

- If either $\|f\|_p = 0$ or $\|g\|_q = 0$ then $fg = 0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.
- $f^p$ and $g^q$ are integrable. Do we know this because we know that $f$ and $g$ are integrable?
- Since $f^p$ and $g^q$ are integrable it follows that $fg$ is integrable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That $\int f\,d\mu=0$ with $f\ge0$ implies $f=0$ a.e. is very basic fare in integration theory. Your first point follows by applying this to either $|f^p|$ or $|g^q|$.
- That $f^p$ and $g^q$ are integrable is the *definition* of $L^p$ and $L^q$.
- The integrability of those two shows that the integral of the right of your inequality is finite. Hence the integral of the left hand side is finite, and you're done.